# How to fix Edge and chrome driver errors of selenium with java project?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge

I downloaded edge driver release version [88](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

Imported selenium standalone server [jar](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) file to my java project.

Trying to execute below code.

```
//TestEdge.java
package com.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

public class TestChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\libs\\msedgedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/");
        driver.quit();
        
    }

}
```

But getting below error.

```
Starting MSEdgeDriver 88.0.688.0 (d760c7e40eea1524171f33a22f8c78145ceb0afe) on port 41783
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping MSEdgeDriver safe.
MSEdgeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find MSEdge binary
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-189RBQR', ip: '192.168.0.7', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.9'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC5832D2+4272850]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC456859+3041369]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC2ACE37+1297975]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC1EF2BC+520892]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC1EC4B0+509104]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC222F42+732994]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC21D98F+711055]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC1F8CF5+560373]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC1F9ADB+563931]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC476808+3172360]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7BC6D5D13+1260179]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7BC6E78B6+1332790]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7BC6D66D9+1262681]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC469B45+3119941]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC478BFB+3181563]
    Ordinal0 [0x00007FF7BC48DE3A+3268154]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFA43BD7C24+20]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFA455CCEA1+33]

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:96)
    at com.test.TestChrome.main(TestChrome.java:12)
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

And I am trying to use adopt openjdk 11 latest version.

And also I tried with chrome driver and I got below error.

```
package com.test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

public class TestChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\libs\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/");
        driver.quit();
        
    }

}
```

Error result:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}) on port 17563
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 87
Current browser version is 86.0.4240.183 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-189RBQR', ip: '192.168.0.7', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.9'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x012EECE3+3337443]
    Ordinal0 [0x011CF041+2158657]
    Ordinal0 [0x01056FA8+618408]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FD1D52+73042]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FCE0D8+57560]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FCC38A+50058]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FF5E8E+220814]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FF5BFC+220156]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FF181B+202779]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FD3D74+81268]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FD4D6E+85358]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FD4CF9+85241]
    Ordinal0 [0x011E6F2C+2256684]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01472FAC+1478332]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01472AFD+1477133]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0147AAD8+1509864]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0147369E+1480110]
    Ordinal0 [0x011DD6BD+2217661]
    Ordinal0 [0x011E89AB+2263467]
    Ordinal0 [0x011E8AEF+2263791]
    Ordinal0 [0x011FD363+2347875]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77276359+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77677C24+228]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77677BF4+180]

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at com.test.TestChrome.main(TestChrome.java:12)
```

Comment: From the exception it seems the chromedriver version you are using and your browser version installed are different. For example: For chrome I can in exception log "Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20" and Current browser version is 86.0.4240.183 there can be version issue check "https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads" for chrome driver version. For MS edge you can follow the guidelines listed in the official site: "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/"

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, I think that's because you used different webdriver version with the browser version. You need to use the matching webdriver version.

For example, if you use Chrome 86.0.4240.183 then you need to use ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22. You can also check and download it in [this page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). It's the same for Edge. Please check your Edge browser version and download the same version of Edge WebDriver in [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

Answer (score -1):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:/Tools/webdrivers/msedgedriver.exe");

DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName(BrowserType.EDGE);
desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("MicrosoftEdge");

Map<String, Object> edgePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
edgePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
edgePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);


EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.setCapability("ms:inPrivate", true);
edgeOptions.setCapability("prefs", edgePrefs);
edgeOptions.setCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);


edgeOptions.merge(desiredCapabilities);
edgeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy("eager");
edgeOptions.setCapability("ms:inPrivate", true);
edgeOptions.setCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
edgeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.HAS_NATIVE_EVENTS, true);
edgeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);
edgeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.HAS_NATIVE_EVENTS, true);
edgeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);

driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.